# Find and replace text in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have SQL Server data in the following format :

```
DECLARE @tblData TABLE 
(
     ID int,
     texttofind varchar(2000),
     txttoReplace varchar(2000),
     Body varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @tblData 
VALUES (1,'url1','someurl1','<href="url1">test</a><href="url2">test2</a><href="url3">test3</a>')

INSERT INTO @tblData 
VALUES (1,'url2','someurl2','<href="url1">test</a><href="url2">test2</a><href="url3">test3</a>')

INSERT INTO @tblData 
VALUES (1,'url3','someurl3','<href="url1">test</a><href="url2">test2</a><href="url3">test3</a>')

INSERT INTO @tblData 
VALUES (2,'url1','someotherurl1','<href="url1">test</a><href="url2">test2</a>')

INSERT INTO @tblData 
VALUES (2,'url2','someotherurl2','<href="url2">test</a><href="url2">test2</a>')


SELECT * FROM @tblData


DECLARE @tblExpectedData TABLE (ID int,
                                texttofind varchar(2000),
                                txttoReplace varchar(2000),
                                Body varchar(max),
                                BodyAfterChange varchar(max)
                               )

INSERT INTO @tblExpectedData 
VALUES (1,'url1','someurl1','<href="url1">test</a><href="url2">test2</a><href="url3">test3</a>','<href="someurl1">test</a><href="someurl2">test2</a><href="someurl3">test3</a>')

INSERT INTO @tblExpectedData 
VALUES (1,'url2','someurl2','<href="url1">test</a><href="url2">test2</a><href="url3">test3</a>','<href="someurl1">test</a><href="someurl2">test2</a><href="someurl3">test3</a>')

INSERT INTO @tblExpectedData 
VALUES (1,'url3','someurl3','<href="url1">test</a><href="url2">test2</a><href="url3">test3</a>','<href="someurl1">test</a><href="someurl2">test2</a><href="someurl3">test3</a>')

INSERT INTO @tblExpectedData 
VALUES (2,'url1','someotherurl1','<href="url1">test</a><href="url2">test2</a>','<href="someotherurl1">test</a><href="someotherurl2">test2</a>')

INSERT INTO @tblExpectedData 
VALUES (2,'url2','someotherurl2','<href="url2">test</a><href="url2">test2</a>','<href="someotherurl1">test</a><href="someotherurl2">test2</a>')

SELECT * FROM @tblExpectedData
```

First table is how the data looks like and second table is how I want the expected result, essentially its doing a find and replace from "texttofind" to "Body" using the "txttoReplace" column but I am unable to figure out how to do it for EACH ID and for each row so that every row for a particular ID has the same "BodyAfterChange "

Comment: any chance this can be parameterized?

Comment: just need a SQL statement which does the update - may it be using Temp table or whatever - is that what you are asking?

Comment: well the problem is the update is based off n number of previous rows with the same ID, which logically only works if it's sorted and the ID isn't reused. So if the data ONLY lives in the same table there are constraints to consider.